# how to launch linux subshell for SSH_ASKPASS to work in linux

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to create a bash script to execute a password-less ssh command with SSH_ASKPASS and DISPLAY variables. In my bash script, I have added parenthesis before and after the command to launch it in a new subshell. The script gets launched in a new shell(Gets a new PID) but TTY is still attached. From my understanding, for SSH_ASKPASS to work, TTY shouldn't be attached. Please let me know if anyone has a solution for this. I want to do it with shell/bash script only.

```
#!/bin/bash
SSH_ASKPASS=/tmp/abc
DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null 10.10.10.10 -lroot /bin/ls
```

/tmp/abc contains just the password

When I execute the script, it asks for the password.

Thanks in Adv.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from ['Force ssh to always use SSH_ASKPASS'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125427/17696): you need to detach the terminal. Try with `setsid`:

```
#!/bin/bash
SSH_ASKPASS=/tmp/abc
DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
setsid ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
           -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null 10.10.10.10 -lroot /bin/ls
```