# ssh with SSH_ASKPASS always fails

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I want to batch-run a command via ssh and have the calling machine determine the exit status and output of that command, but where the password is known in advance and *not* typed by hand.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945815/how-to-launch-linux-subshell-for-ssh-askpass-to-work-in-linux) seems to be what I want, but it doesn't work.

Pre-flight check:

```
#> ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null testuser@localhost 'echo here' && echo ok || echo no
Warning: Permanently added '[localhost]:22' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
testuser@localhost's password: 
here
ok
```

Good start. Now bundle this with SSH_ASKPASS

```
#!/bin/bash

u="testuser"
p="testpassword"

ask="/tmp/ask"

echo "echo $p" > $ask
chmod +x $ask

SSH_ASKPASS=$ask
DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
setsid ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null $u@localhost 'echo here' && echo ok || echo no
```

Ignore the security problems, this is just a POC.

When I run this

```
#> /tmp/test.sh
Warning: Permanently added '[localhost]:22' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
no
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Afaik, you need to export the variables. Running the `ssh` with `-vvv` would tell you that the `ASKPASS` is not used.

Comment: That works. Want to make it a full answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export the environment variables to apply for your `ssh` command:

```
export DISPLAY
export SSH_ASKPASS
```

Running the `ssh` with `-vvv` would tell you that the `SSH_ASKPASS` command is not used.